# Narita transfer to Henada for connecting flight

Tags: visas

I am arriving from the Philippines (with Philippine passport and tourist US Visa) to JAL at Narita airport on July 5 at 1:00PM and and departing from JAL at Haneda at 5:15PM going to Newark Liberty New Jersey?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  Can you clarify what your question is?